# Intellisense has lost track of NewtonSoft.Json

Tags: visual-studio-2013, json.net, intellisense

Working in a (VS2013) project that's been using Newtonsoft.Json successfully for quite a while. During today's editing session Intellisense has lost it's reference to Json.net objects -- and i'm sure there's a more accurate way to express this - +1 for that tidbit -- but here's the behavior:

[image: screen cap of json.net problem]

So here Intellisense is insisting that, while JsonConvert is valid, the DeserializeObject method cannot be resolved.

another example:
[image: screen cap of json.net problem]

Mousing over the squiggle tosses: Constructor 'JProperty' has 0 parameters but is invoked with 2 arguments.

The code compiles and runs correctly so the problem exists within Intellisense itself. This is the second time in as many months that Json.net has behaved this way. Last time i was able to restore normal behavior by 'Update-Package...'. This time that's not working. Json.Net is the only component I've see act this way. It's also worth adding that an associate who is working on the same solution (via GIT synchs) does _not see this behavior.

ADDENDUM: I've rebooted and correct Intellisense behavior is restored. But is hosed again as soon as I execute a 'Clean Solution' op.

Comment: Maybe you have an older version of Json.Net installed in your GAC?

Comment: I've dumped the output of gacutil -l to a text file and searched for 'newton' and 'json.n' with no hits.